# Using definition of pre-image to prove $ X \subset f^{-1}(f(X)) $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove easy statements such as one listed here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pre-Image.html

My attempt: let $ x \in X$ then $f(x) \in f(X)$ so $x \in f^{-1}(f(X))$ but I am not really doing anything but looking at the definitions - how may i formalise this?

Comment: You're ok. Indeed, it is a formal argument

Comment: That's formal enough. It *is* just a "definition chase" — that's why it's an easy statement!